# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Async not working

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

One of the strangest problem I have ever seen.
I'm making an async SQL request using entityframework

Environment:
Dotnet core
nuget Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 3.1.19

It works in Visual Studio.
It fails when deployed in Kubernetes Cluster:

- WITHOUT CRASH
- WITHOUT RAISING EXCEPTION
- THE PROGRAM just EXITS !

  ```
    public Job GetJobById(int jobId)
    {
        using ManagerContext context = new ManagerContext(_callContext);            
        Job job = context.Jobs.Where(j => j.Id == jobId).FirstOrDefault();
        return job;
    }
    public async Task<List<Job>> GetJobs(Expression<Func<Job, bool>> expression = default)
    {            
        using ManagerContext context = new ManagerContext(_callContext);           
        IQueryable<Job> jobs;
        if (expression == default)
            jobs = context.Jobs;
        else
            jobs = context.Jobs.Where(expression);           
        return await jobs.ToListAsync();
    }
  ```

[image]
Analysis:
The call  **Job job = context.Jobs.Where(j => j.Id == jobId).FirstOrDefault();** works and returns the value.

The same request written async **return await jobs.ToListAsync();** silently fails.

If you check the picture below, you will notice that code after the call is not called and we did not enter the catch either.

The program just exits without crashing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

solved.

The call at the top level of the stack trace was non blocking and the program just exited gracefully.